# ¿Cómo dividir en dos divs el tamaño total de una página html en cualquier resolución?

Tags: html5, css

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo puedo dividir en dos `div` el tamaño total de una página html en cualquier resolución?**

Es decir un `div` que me ocupe el 50% del alto de la página y otro que me ocupe el otro 50% que queda.

Esto para que mis contenedores (divs) queden siempre ocupando todo el alto la pagina (50 y 50 %).

Comment: Has echo un viste a Bootstrap?

Comment: Me refiero a como ocupar el espacio verticalmente (div1 height: 50% y div2 height:50%) quedando uno encima de otro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando porcentajes podrías hacer algo así:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.contenedor{
  height: 49%;
  background-color: #6A737C;
  margin: 1% 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: ¿Por qué ese `margin:1% 1%`? Hace que los `div` en lugar de ocupar 100% de la altura de la página ocupen un 102%

Comment: Realmente puse ese `margin:1% 1%;` para diferenciar los divs, pero puede ser por que el css no esta normalizado, se podría poner `html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}` para normalizarlo.

Comment: Era solo curiosidad

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta de Juan Pinzón es buena, yo te voy a poner una alternativa usando Flexbox.

La idea es tener un contenedor `flex` que ocupe el 100% del alto de la página y que tenga la propiedad [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) con valor `column` (de este modo los elementos van a expandirse en dirección vertical en lugar de horizontal como ocurre con el valor por defecto `row`). Entonces sus descendientes tendrán `flex:1` que hará que se distribuyan uniformemente dentro del contenedor.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```css
html, body { 
  height:100%; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.contenedor {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height:100%;
}

.contenedor > div {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
}

.fila0 { background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
.fila1 { background:rgba(255,0,0,0.3); }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="fila0">A</div>
  <div class="fila1">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si es para toda la página puedes usar unidades `vh`, no tienes que definir una altura para las etiquetas `html` y `body`, siempre es relativo al tamaño del navegador. En cambio si esos dos `div` están en un contenedor y quieres que ocupen la mitad de ese contenedor tendrás que usar porcentajes o flexbox como te indican Álvaro y Juan.

Este es mi ejemplo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```